# How to reverse a mutate command in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, char, mutate

I am doing the Bellabeat case study from the google analytics course. I am doing it in R and noticed that the date format was in character format rather than "Date" so I tried to use the `mutate()` function to convert it to a date format.

The dataframe is called `sleep`

The code looks as:

```
sleep <- sleep %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(Date))
```

But instead of converting it to a date format it went from this:

```
         Id       Date TotalSleepRecords TotalMinutesAsleep TotalTimeInBed
1 1503960366 4/12/2016                  1                327            346
2 1503960366 4/13/2016                  2                384            407
3 1503960366 4/15/2016                  1                412            442
4 1503960366 4/16/2016                  2                340            367
5 1503960366 4/17/2016                  1                700            712
6 1503960366 4/19/2016
```

to,

```
> head(sleep)
          Id Date TotalSleepRecords TotalMinutesAsleep TotalTimeInBed date
1 1503960366 <NA>                 1                327            346 <NA>
2 1503960366 <NA>                 2                384            407 <NA>
3 1503960366 <NA>                 1                412            442 <NA>
4 1503960366 <NA>                 2                340            367 <NA>
5 1503960366 <NA>                 1                700            712 <NA>
6 1503960366 <NA>                 1                304            320 <NA>
```

What exactly did I do wrong and how can I revert it?

My purpose with the dataframes I work with is to compare how exercise impacts sleep. I am not sure if I actually need to convert the date format, but many others who did the case study did it, so I figured that it might impact the analysis if I do not do it. There are several other dataframes in the package I work with. I figure I need to merge dataframes to compare columns.

Comment: because the format is not year then month then day ie `ymd` but rather you should use `mdy` function since you have month then day then year

Comment: Also, you should never overwrite the dataset unless you are very sure your function works and does what you want. Consider using another variable to store your mutated dataset, or mutate on a new column

Comment: You cannot undo the problem. You will have to read the data afresh into the R environment

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the replies, since your dates are in "mm/dd/yyyy" format you should use `lubridate::mdy()` to convert them to dates.

As a general workflow tip, it's a good idea to check what the results of your operation would be before overwriting the dataframe. For example if I have

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sleep <- tibble(id = c(1, 2), date = c("4/12/2016", "4/13/2016"))
```

then in the console I can try out the operation first:

```
sleep %>%
   mutate(date = mdy(date))

#>      id date      
#>   <dbl> <date>    
#> 1     1 2016-04-12
#> 2     2 2016-04-13
```

Now that I'm satisfied my mutation has done what I want it to, I can save the results. I tend to save the results to a new dataframe:

```
sleep_clean <- sleep %>%
   mutate(date = mdy(date))
```

so that I can still access the original `sleep` dataframe after (thus 'reverting' to the previous version).